# Dismiss removes multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm having some problems with the dismiss functionality within a view controller.

Let me start from the beginning.

- I login to my app and I'm taken to the main dashboard page.
- I click my navigation button to open up my navigation page, which is open as a model.
- On the nav page I click the button to view my profile.
- On the my profile page I choose the edit icon to go to the edit profile page.
- On the edit profile page and I choose to select an avatar.

So in total I open up 5 different page when I dismiss the last one it take me all the way back to the navigation, which is effectively dismissing 3 pages. Is there something I have to do so it only dismisses the last view controller?

I have a page to select an avatar which is opened like this:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Profile", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserAvatarController") as! UserAvatarController
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
viewController.avatars = self.avatars
viewController.delegate = self

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

When I have selected my avatar on the page a click a button and that triggers this:

```
if (self.selectedImage > -1) {
    self.delegate?.selectAvatar(imageId: self.selectedImage)
}

self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It then take me back all the way to be navigation page and loses all the data from the edit profile page.

Comment: why mark my question down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are opening view with pushViewController and closing the view with dismiss.

You are supposed to close the view with pop.

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Hope this will fix your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot :) that works a treat. I will get the hang of all this, most likely just before apple changes it all again lol

Answer (score 1):

Just do `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`
It will go back to previous view controller.